# list.dirs but output a list with nested folders

Tags: r

I was wondering---base R's `list.dirs` gives you a character vector with the nested folder structure all flattened to a character vector. Is there a function to return a list of folders as class `list` instead? That is to say, if `./a/b/c` existed, the current `list.dirs` returns

```
[1] "a"                                                                       
[2] "a/b"                                                        
[3] "a/b/c"
```

but instead return something like

```
$`a`
$`a`$`b`
$`a`$`b`$`c`
[1] "a/b/c"
```

Perhaps I'm missing a simple existing solution?

Comment: Don't you need output as list of length 3 ? The current output is only for 3rd element?

Comment: @RonakShah I think I was envisioning having the list imitate the folder structure, so that you can do `l$a`, `l$a$b`, and `l$a$b$c`, but yes I guess that only shows the output for the bottom of the nest (does this make sense?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a simple solution to this but I wrote a function which does something similar

```
recur.list <- function(x, y) {
    if(length(x) == 1)
     setNames(list(y), x[1])
    else
     setNames(list(recur.list(x[-1], y)), x[1])
}

listed_list.dirs <- function(folder_name) {
      vec <- strsplit(folder_name, "/")
      mapply(recur.list, vec, folder_name)
}
```

Basically `recur.list` is a recursive function which creates a nested list based on the depth of the folders whereas `listed_list.dirs` splits the folder name on "/" and creates a separate vector of characters for each of the `folder_name`.

```
x <- c("a","a/b","a/b/c")
listed_list.dirs(x)

#$a
#[1] "a"

#$a
#$a$b
#[1] "a/b"


#$a
#$a$b
#$a$b$c
#[1] "a/b/c"
```

Another example

```
listed_list.dirs("Users/ronakshah/Downloads/")

#$Users
#$Users$ronakshah
#$Users$ronakshah$Downloads
#[1] "Users/ronakshah/Downloads/"
```